# How to get string with pattern from std::regex in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-c++-2010

Can I get the string with regular expression from `std::regex`? Or should I save it somewhere else if I want to use it later?

In boost you can do this:

```
boost::regex reg("pattern");
string p = reg.str();
```

or use << operator

`cout << reg;` will print *pattern*.

but in `std::regex` there is no str() or operator<<. Should I save my string somewhere else or I just can't find it?

In debugger I can see what's in `std::regex`.

Comment: Please edit this question, I very much doubt that given `"pattern"` it will print `aaa`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just looked in N3225, section 28.4 (header `<regex>` synopsis) and indeed, the `basic_regex` template has no member function `str`, and there are no `operator<<` provided.

The paragraph 28.8/2 provides *a little insight* on this :

> Objects of type specialization of
>   `basic_regex` are responsible for
>   converting the sequence of `charT`
>   objects to **an internal representation**.
>   It is not specified what form this
>   representation takes, nor how it is
>   accessed by algorithms that operate on
>   regular expressions.

What I understand is that the standard mandates that `basic_regex` can be constructed from `const charT *` but does not require the implementation to keep this string.

Answer (score 4):

[The MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926112.aspx) seem to show that there's no publicly accessible way to retrieve the regex pattern from a constructed object, so I would say that you need to save the string yourself.