# How can I hash a std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, hash, stl

I need to hash a class which has a `std::regex` as a member which is initialized from a string in the class' constructor.

To get a good hash for the class, I could either store the hash of the pattern string in the constructor or -- the preferred way -- compute a hash of the regex itself. Is this possible (preferrably without boost)?

More precisely: I would like to calculate

```
std::hash<std::regex>{}(m_regex);
```

where m_regex is of type `std::regex`, but the template specialization for `std::regex` does not exist.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std you're allowed to extend `std` to add your own specialization for `std::hash`.

Comment: @GillBates: But are you allowed to do it for types from the standard library? `std::regex` isn't a user-defined type (in any way), so I'm not sure if specializing `std::hash` for it would be considered well-defined or undefined behavior.

Comment: Hashing is useless if you cannot check for equality to rule out hash collisions, and `std::regex` doesn't provide any `operator==` you could use for that.

Comment: Btw, is there a reason why std::regex does not provide a `==`-operator? I can not think of why regexes should not be comparable...

Comment: @jafasi When would two regexes compare as equal? When they're constructed from the same string, when they consist of the same internal representation, or when they match the same input? The first requires storing a string in a way that would be useless for most programs. The second means implementations won't be able to agree on which regexes should and shouldn't compare as equal. The third is very difficult to implement, much more difficult than needed to get basic regex functionality working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *cannot* hash a [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) object, because it's assumed to have an [internal representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4501138/1621391) (which may not be portable). Remember a `std::regex` object carries some [other information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex#Constants). If you were thinking of using the regex pattern string used to construct the object (or assigned), you still can't because you cannot retrieve the string used to construct an `std::regex` object because, [it isn't required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30991076/1621391) to store the string.

---

A probable workaround is to save both the string and the [flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/flags) used to construct the `std::regex` object, then construct a regex object whenever you need.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant in my question and what I am currently doing: saving the hash (of the string) at construction-time. I just wondered whether there is some better way.

Comment: @jafasi. Nope, there's no other way I know of. I think of a `std::regex` as some sort of resource.